# self hosted asp.net webapi basic authentication no 401 returned on windows 2008

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have developed a self hosted asp.net webapi service that uses basic authentication using message handlers (similar to this: http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/).  When I run this from my workstation (win 7 x64), the client consumes as expected.  When I run this on the intended server (win 2008), the client fails with error code 500.  After a bit of digging and network tracing, it looks like the (working) win 7 box initially responds with 401 as expected, but the win 2008 box doesn't respond at all, it just drops the connection (the client reports this as 500).

I've setup a remote debug on the server, and there's not even a stack track to go on.  It looks to me like maybe I'm missing some component on the server that is causing an exception somewhere deep in the asp.net webapi code, but I can't tell for sure.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here.  The only next step I can think of is to run procmon against it and see if it comes up with any 'file-not-found' type entries for dll's.

Comment: Try adding the NuGet for tracing and see if this highlights the issue http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.tracing

Comment: Same result - I get a log entry from the dev box, but nothing from the production box

Comment: How are you deploying this application? Is there anything in the servers EventLog, there should be something to say which DLL could not be found.

Comment: I am just doing a file copy deployment.  No - there are no entries in the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using the asp.net web stack nightly builds so that i could get better symbol information (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/29/using-nightly-nuget-packages-with-asp-net-web-stack.aspx).  With that, and turning on .net framework debugging, I was able to capture the actual exception that was being thrown:

The 'WWW-Authenticate' header cannot be modified directly

Googling that, I found several leads, one of which led to http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/287534 where I got a solution.  Basically, switch to using authentication in an authentication module instead of doing it in message handling.  So more like this:

```cs
HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://0.0.0.0:" + FaxCommon.SERVICE_PORT.ToString());
config.UserNamePasswordValidator = new AuthenticationProvider();
```

Where AuthenticationProvider is a subclass of UserNamePasswordValidator

After doing that, the code works everywhere.